# Nginx container as proxy cache for Tomcat container

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, tomcat

I'm trying to use nginx as proxy cache for tomcat, using two separate containers. I've created a nginx container from official nginx image; same for tomcat, listening on port 8080.

Now, how should i configure nginx as proxy cache for tomcat content?

Contents in tomcat webserver are in the path: localhost:8080/shaka-player-master/demo/

This is nginx.conf in /etc/nginx:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I have to tell that there are, from nginx docker official image, folders /etc/nginx/sites-available nor /etc/nginx/site-enabled.

I want tell that in path /usr/share/nginx/html/ of nginx container there is only an index.html created automatically from nginx image. The unique other configuration file is under /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf... :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
         proxy_cache my_zone;
         add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/shaka-player-master/demo;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

My gol is: when i run http://localhost:9000 (or some other path on the same port), the first time (cache miss) i could give content from localhost:8080/shaka-player-master/demo/index.html

and then, when i reload localhost:9000, there is a cache hit.

I would use nginx as proxy cache because i would to setup a CDN using more nginx instances (containers).

I hope someone could help me in that nginx configuration, because i'm spending a lot of time trying to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your config that would enable caching. The definition of **proxy** is: a server that acts as an intermediary. Sometimes it *can* cache, sometimes it does other intermediary stuff. The `proxy_pass` doesn't implement caching.

[The simplest ngingx caching](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) is `proxy_cache_path` plus `proxy_cache`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @kubanczyk. I've already read your link and i've found this: https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching . I've edited my two config files.. do you think it's all correct or there are some other problems?